# Generate Styled Component from Serialized String

Tags: styled-components

Is it possible to create a Styled Component from a serialized string? Do I need to parse my string out into actual functions to support interpolated variations? Example of a string I might store:

```
// this is a serialized string from storage:

background-color: black;

${p => p.white && css`
  background-color: white;
`}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
const MyComp = styled.div`
  ${myComponentStringFromStorage}
`;

<MyComp white /> // works, but displays the black background
```

This works for the base CSS rules, but it misses my functions as they're just passing in as text in the string and not real functions.

I'm guessing that I need to write a parser to break my string into real functions that I send into the styled component factory function?

Curious if Styled Components has a built in helper function for this, or if there's a different approach.

Comment: I'm curious, is the serialized string direct user input? Or are you processing user input from a css gui/form and composing the serialized string behind the scenes, then storing that in the db? The reason I'm asking is I had a few possible solutions, depending on if you need to support a user actually writing out css functions directly (like the serialize string first example).

Comment: Hey Stephen – it's the second. I'm taking input at the individual property level... and then composing it together into a string for export and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` on your stored string together with `styled.div` as a string in order to create a component out of it.

```js
const MyComp = eval("styled.div`" + myComponentStringFromStorage + "`");
```

Keep in mind that `eval` might be dangerous, and that this will be done at runtime, so it will not work in environments that don't support template strings.

```js
const { css } = styled;

const myComponentStringFromStorage = [
  "background-color: black;\n",
  "\n",
  "${p => p.white && css`\n",
  "  background-color: white;\n",
  "`}"
].join("");

const MyComp = eval("styled.div`" + myComponentStringFromStorage + "`");

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyComp white>Foo</MyComp>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tholle, this is kind of what I figured. Your solution does work well, thanks for typing it out. I went ahead and awarded the bounty. Cheers.